# Type checking with a varargs function

Tags: scala, variadic-functions

If I define this (nonsense) function:

```
def g[A](f: (A*) => A): Int = {
  10
}
```

Why doesn't the compiler type checks the following case?

```
def add(x: Int, y: Int) = x+ y

g(add)
```

I mean, shouldn't `(A, A)` type check to `(A*)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(A, A)` is a *tuple* (`Tuple2`) and therefore it does not type-check to `(A*)`. Only functions that actually take `A*` can be passed to `g`, e.g.:

```
def add(ints: Int*): Int = ints.sum
```

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestion about how can I abstract over the arity without asking the user to write functions thinking about sequences, eg `ints.sum`?

Comment: Or `def add(ints: Seq[Int])`. `add _` used to preserve the repeated param.